# Finding the height

Tags: list, haskell, tree

I have the following data type

`data Tree a -> Node a [Tree a]`

and would like to find the labels of all the Nodes and height of the tree.

Here is what I did:

```
height:: Tree a -> Integer height

 (Node _ (x:xs)) = 1 + maximum height' (x:xs)
 height' (x:xs) = map height (x:xs)
```

I was hoping that height' would return a list of height mapped over x:xs and try to find the max of that value but ghci does not approve of the map function here.

Comment: "fails because xs is a list of trees and not a single tree like the function type signature indicates" - then why are you applying `labels` to the list `xs`? You want to apply it _to each element_ of this list, and the function that does exactly this is...? You also don't need to separate `x` from `xs` in `labels.

Comment: Because Im not sure how I apply to each element in a list instead of the whole list..

Comment: you're almost there. You should `map` this function over your list: `labels (Node label children) = label : (map labels children)`

Comment: I tried doing that earlier but get an error saying :```Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
      Expected type: [a]
        Actual type: [[a]]```

Comment: I recommend to you to add the labels function in another question, with the full stack error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking in account I defined the Tree as:

```
data GenTree a = NodeG a [GenTree a] deriving (Show)
```

Well, in this one you where a little closer:

```
height:: GenTree a -> Integer
height (NodeG _ [])    = 0 -- Deep 0
height (NodeG _ trees) = 1 + (maximum $ heightLs trees) -- take the max

-- (maximum $ heightLs trees) == (maximum (heightLs trees))

heightLs (x:xs) = map height (x:xs) -- here is perfect

genTree1 = NodeG "1" [NodeG "2" [],
                         NodeG "3" [NodeG "4" [],
                                   NodeG "5" [NodeG "6" [],
                                             NodeG "7" [],
                                             NodeG "8" [
                                                        NodeG "9" []
                                                        ]
                                             ]
                                   ]
                         ]
```

> Example

```
$>   height genTree1
=> 4
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write this in a one liner with:

```
height :: Integral i => Tree a -> i
height (Node _ cs) = 1 + maximum (0 : map height cs)
```

Here for every node, we thus return `1 + …` where `…` is the maximum of `0` and the heights of the children of these nodes. We here use `0` to prevent that, if the `Node` hase no children, the `maximum` will work over an empty list, and thus raise an error.